# rails 4 def to_param with 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4, url-rewriting

I came accross something strange when trying to create friendly URLs.

I have an item model which has:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{name}".parameterize
end
```

This makes my item URLs contain the "ID" and "name" just fine:

```
www.domain.com/items/ID-name
```

I also have a category model (item belongs to category and user models) where I have the same def to_param as above but the category URLs stay "unfriendly" no "name" included:

```
domain.com/categories/ID
```

I have name column in category table and it has values. 
I also use ancestry for the category model. Maybe has_ancestry is causing the issue?

I tried below but no luck:

```
def to_param
 [id, name.parameterize].join("-")
end
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Note that `to_param` only works if you are passing a resource to the link helper (`link_to(@user.name, @user)`) or if you use `to_param` `user_path(@user.to_param)` make sure you are not calling `.id` instead

Comment: There is `gem` that does everything you need about friendly id urls, [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Comment: thanks #papirtiger, that lead me to apidock and got solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Papirtiger's comment lead me to the solution.
The problem was I had links like:

```
<% @category.children.in_groups_of(4, false) do |childs| %>
 <tr>
 <% for categories in childs %>
 <td>
 <%= link_to "../categories/#{categories.id}" do %><%= categories.name %><% end %></td>
 <% end %>
 </tr>
```

Beginners solution. :)

Removed the ugly part and now it works:

```
<% @category.children.in_groups_of(4, false) do |childs| %>
 <tr>
 <% for categories in childs %>
 <td><%= link_to categories do %><%= categories.name %><% end %> (<%= Item.where(:category_id => categories.id).count %>)</td>
 <% end %>
 </tr>
```